# Delphi Indy no response content after 404

Tags: delphi, indy

When Indy get a 404, I cannot get the response content, its always empty.

For example, using Indy to access https://www.etsy.com/people/car, I get a 404 and contentstream (or assigned stream) is just empty.
Doing the same with THttpClient, I also get a 404, but also get the content of the 404 page in the response stream.

So my question is, how can I get the response content with Indy when its a 404?

Comment: Is the content stored in the `ErrorMessage` of `EIdHTTPProtocolException`, like with the Indy 403 error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607876/indy-http-reading-response-content-on-a-403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> using Indy to access https://www.etsy.com/people/car, I get a 404 and contentstream (or assigned stream) is just empty.

This is the default behavior, by design, to prevent corrupting the output with unexpected error data that was not requested.

> how can I get the response content with Indy when its a 404?

There are two possible ways:

1. By default, `TIdHTTP` raises an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception on an HTTP error.  The response data will be in its `ErrorMessage` property.
2. You can avoid the raised exception by either:

   - enabling the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.
   - using the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that has an `AIgnoreReplies` parameter, passing 404 (or any other error response code you want) in that parameter.

   Either way, by default the response data will still be discarded. You can avoid that by enabling the recently added `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property (see [New TIdHTTP flags and OnChunkReceived event](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20160110.EN.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks Remy, answer fully accepted. I use the ErrorMessage value and it works now just fine!